# Why is a domain user unable to log on into a Windows 7 machine when Samba server signing is enabled?

Tags: linux, active-directory, windows-7, samba

I have an up and running Linux-based domain controller running Samba. The server functions properly as I am able to join Windows 7 machines to my domain and then log on into the machine using my test users.

The problem is when I enable server signing on Samba. For test purposes, I added a new machine to the domain but this time I am unable to log on into the machine using my test users. I have tested it several times and it seems to me that the problem comes from the server signing.

Here are details of my server:

```
Linux UBUNTU precise 12.04.5
Samba 3.6.3
```

The error message is:

```
There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request
```

In order to ensure that the problem does not stem from a machine internal password mismatch as pointed in some other posts, I made sure to add the machine to the domain with the server signing setting enabled on the Samba server (interestingly it works).

Does anyone have any idea why the server no longer responds to logon request when server signing is enabled?

Comment: Have you verified that your Win7 client has SMBv2/3 enabled?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some google search, I found a tutorial that specified pointing fqdn and server name to the localhost in the hosts file i.e.

```
127.0.1.1   hostname.domainname.org  hostname
```

Hope this helps.